# reporting library for flex 4

Tags: flex4, reporting

I look for a reporting library for flex 4 which it is an open source one or a free one.
Can i suggest me libraries? If they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [KapLab Kolbert reporting](http://lab.kapit.fr/display/kaplabhome/Home) components. It's free for non commercial usage.

Alos, [Axiis](http://www.axiis.org/) components are open-source I think